# Recording Vimeo Uploads To SQL

Tags: sql, asp-classic, vimeo-api

We're currently looking at using Vimeo Pro to upload videos for a website we're developing. What we want to do is, once a video is uploaded, record the data to an SQL database so we can embed the video to specific pages using database calls rather then hard coding.

So what I need to know is, can Vimeo return the code I need so I can record it?

Comment: Why don't you ask Vimeo

Comment: Well, Vimeo's website suggests asking here if I can't find an answer in the documentation.

Comment: Vimeo's [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/vimeo-api) is generally intended for questions that are not directly programming related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To embed a video you need to generate an embed code through Vimeo's [oEmbed endpoint](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/oembed).
- The oEmbed endpoint works off of the on site Vimeo URL, which is provided in the "link" field on any video response (such as [GET /videos/{video_id}](http://developer.vimeo.dev/api/playground/videos/%7Bvideo_id%7D))
- I would recommend storing the Vimeo URL, not the embed code, since the embed codes might change and improve over time.

Comment: Good advice. +1 (URL is broken though - should be http://developer.vimeo.com/api/playground/videos/%7Bvideo_id%7D I think).